# How can I make parent width equal to child width?

Tags: html, css

This is probably a silly question, but I'm new to this. It is possible to have a parent width equals to a child width?
Let me show you my problem. I have this navbar:

```
<navbar>
  <ul>
    <li>word X</li>
    <li>word Y</li>
    <li> A ▼
      <ul>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
      </ul>
    </li>

    <li> B ▼
      <ul>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</navbar>
```

My 'ul' that is inside 'A', has a width that changes depending on his content, and I want his parent ('A') to be the same width. Can I achieve this?
This is what is happening.

[image]

Comment: Be default unless you set the width of the parent element or add padding/a border to it then it should be as large as it's content, in this case the parent A would be as large as the ul inside it. Maybe I am not grasping what you're actually are trying to achieve. Can you provide an example of what this would look?

Comment: Hello, I edited my post. There is an image of my problem now. Thanks ;)

Comment: Ups I founded the problem!! I had my child with position absolute, that was running everything. Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible.
Give this style to your ul element:

```
ul {
  display: inline-block;
  width: auto;
}
```

Comment: Hi, 
This will change his parent width?

Comment: Ups I founded the problem!! I had my child with position absolute, that was running everything. Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

By displaying block it will take all the available space.

```
   ul, li { display: block)
   navbar > ul {display: inline-block}
```

Answer (score 0):

change your child elements width to inherit and it will automatically follow the parent's width.
`width: inherit`
if not working then put some width to parent and try again.